# グローバル変数宣言時に、代入しないとエラーになる理由

Tags: javascript

グローバル変数宣言と同時に代入するとエラー表示されないのですが

```
a=1;
```

グローバル変数宣言だけだとエラーになるのはなぜですか？

```
a;
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

---

「var a;」はOKで「a;」がNGな理由は、仕様だから？？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a;`は、変数を宣言しているのではなく参照しているからです。（既にある変数として値を読み出す。（そしてその値は捨てる））

Comment: ちなみに`a=1;`は暗黙の宣言(`var a=1;`だとみなされる(他に宣言がなく最初の場合))です。参考：[var ステートメント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/z16cackw(v=vs.94).aspx)